# How to construct confidence intervals for difference of means in logs

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution, logarithm, ratio

I have estimated an OLS model and a Negative binomial model of ln housing search (ln S) per unit (for instance, the average number of visitors per house or bidders per house) as a function of predictors. Then I predict ln S at various levels of 2 of the predictors (High, Medium and Low quality) and (boom exp, boom con, bust con, bust exp market phases) while setting the rest of the regressors at mean value.

This generates "predictions of the mean response" along with SE's for these various cases, see the example for the neg bin model and for the boom exp case:

[image: Negative Binomial model predictions]

E.g., the predicted ln Search for L quality during Boom exp is 2,983687 with SE 0,025104.
However, what I am really interested in is the differences in search for L relative to M quality during this market phase: ln(S_L) - ln(S_M), which should be approximately equal to their percentage difference.

Q1: How to construct confidence intervals for this difference? We can think of it as coming from two different samples since the quality classes are mutually exclusive. My main interest is to compare mean search for L,M, and H quality by market phase.

Q2: Should I construct the CI's differently for the neg bin and ols cases?

Here are figures of the mean search percentage difference (ln(S_L) -ln(S_M)), based on the predictions, for the two cases:

[image: Predicted search difference by house quality and market phase, OLS and neg bin model]

[image]